# Can i have input for creating a Build Tool?

Tags: build

I'm a student and i want make a build tool as a side project for myself because none of the current build tools seem to attract me. There's ant, but i really dislike looking at XML (i don't know why, but i really don't see the appeal of tags; it puts me off visually and cannot be made neat in my eyes). There's maven, but i really don't want to be working on a project just to have it fail all of a sudden (this is based on the research I've done where people say that there are times that maven fails to build all of a sudden. This could just be total BS but i'd rather not find out the hard way), plus there's some XML involved. I really liked make, but it isn't portable, and even though the chances of me using a non-Windows PC are next to nil, I am unfortunately, a computer science student who has been properly trained to always assume the worst case.

Currently, i am looking into Gradle. I'm still trying to figure it out (i am a really slow learner) but i like the syntax. It might also be beneficial to note that i am so shallow that i don't really care about the back end stuff or any of the advanced features cause i don't really understand dependency management and stuff just quite yet. All i care about is that the configuration syntax or make file looks clean, that it works without requiring internet access, absolute paths, or anything of the sort, and that it works consistently and doesn't take too long. I believe that the syntax is important because, like all code, if it looks ugly, you won't want to read it.

I want to make a build tool that is simple, functional, and portable (i'm gonna be running it off my External HDD with Java in it). I'd really appreciate any suggestions this community has to offer, such as "It really is better to just stick with ant or maven cause they work already" or "be sure to avoid make's dependency issue". This will just be a side project so i can work on my Java and maybe learn something new so even if i fail, i still might learn something new so no need to comment on that.

Comment: It seems strange that you're looking for input from other people, because you don't seem to want what other people find useful (ant, maven). So my suggestion is to figure out what you want, without trying to please anyone else, then implement that. If you're a competent programmer, and think through your tool, you won't crash and burn. And will learn something about build processes in the meantime.

Comment: i am sorry about the lack of clarity on my comment about maven, i tried to clear that up in this edition of my question. Thank you all for your replies and i will take everything posted into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's just an idea:

`ant` is really not such a bad tool. Maybe you could consider building a front end for it that translates a DSL (Domain Specific Language) of your own design into ant's XML, and hide the XML from your tool's users?

---

You may also want to take a look at [Rake](http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html). Someone recently ranted in his blog about how terrible Maven is (and the debate goes on) and he much, much prefers Rake.

Comment: With that in mind, I've seen this ant GUI before and it looks like it might be of use:

http://antsnest.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

Another existing tool you might choose to ignore is SCons.  It's written in Python and has some very nice features including, possibly relevant to you, easy extensibility.

And yes, I think you are going to crash and burn. Far better to learn one of the existing tools properly than to reinvent this particular wheel.  Use your creative urges and time to write something truly new.

Furthermore, and since you are a student allow me to stand on my soap-box: one of the lessons that new entrants to the IT profession have to learn is to use the tools you are given, not to expect to be allowed the time and money to develop a new one.  Don't expect to be able to rock up to work on day one and try to make a case for writing 'MyMake' because GNU Make (or whatever) doesn't float your boat.

Comment: Thanks for the slightly derogatory, but nonetheless useful bit of advice. I forgot to consider what happens when i start working and have to learn ant or maven.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already tried it, try [Automated Build Studio](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/abs/). We have used if for a couple of years now and it works fine for us.

Answer (score 2):

I started one, some 7 years ago. I am still using it. No one else uses it. http://gna.org/projects/maker/

I started on some same ground than you: multi platform (was Linux, DEC Alpha, and Windows at the time) with a new shiny lanquage: Python. I was getting ideas from Miller's [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) in the sense that I had a source file for each executable (same for shared library, or static library) that was listing the C/C++ source files, and dependencies on other libraries. The main feature was to generate on the fly a makefile that is fed into gmake (that does a perfect job, provided it has a perfect makefile) to build all the binaries in one call, managing all the dependencies (with gcc -MD options).

Over time. it evolved mostly into a tool that can use Visual Studio C++ project and solution files to compile on Linux. And I am struggling to keep it up-to-date with new versions of Visual, and new values of project parameters and project properties that my coworkers use.

I wouldn't recommend starting a new tool.

Answer (score 0):

Why would using Maven mean that your build fails "all of a sudden"?

I would advocate always using continuous integration (e.g. cruise control for ant or Hudson for maven) regardless of the build tool you use.  This should eliminate a build failing "all of a sudden"

Comment: If you don't disabuse Maven of updating all dependencies from the Internet on every operation, then it's quite possible that one of the authors of one of your dependencies changes *his* POM's dependencies in a way that will make your build fail. It's this dependency on external influences that gives Maven a bad name. Well, that's one thing.

Answer (score 0):

> There's maven, but i really don't want to be working on a project just to have it fail all of a sudden.

What does that mean?

Anyway, if you're into Groovy, I recommend [Gant](http://gant.codehaus.org/).

Comment: See my comment to James B. The OP may be overstating, but not by much.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was merely making a point that if someone (the OP in this case) makes such a statement, s/he should back it up a bit.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not into groovy, but i'll look into Gant. Also, i fixed the maven comment so yeah...

Answer (score 0):

Cobbling together your own build tool doesn't sound like a great use of your time, especially when established tools such as ant and maven exist and have such vast user bases that are finding (and fixing) bugs with those tools.

I don't understand your comment about maven causing build failure all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

XML will haunt you everywhere you go. Invest in an excellent XML visualizer / editor, and go to town with Ant anyhow!